# How to vertically align item in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align text inside of a column. If I use `my-auto` in the parent (column), then it vertically aligns the text, but it pulls in everything to the center and I need to maintain the background. The background color is currently on the column.

When I remove `my-auto`, the full orange background returns, but the text is at the top.

I've tried creating an inner row>column structure to account for it, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 my-auto" style="background-color: #f04e23;">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center">2018 Speakers</h1>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `"message": "Script error.",` You need to load jQuery prior to bootstrap.min.js.

Comment: @connexo - it's fixed.

Comment: Could always do `style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%)"` on your `h1` or a class equivalent to get your desired result....

Comment: That still destroys my background color. Here's a **[codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/MPmvMO)** for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using margins, set the column's display to flex by adding the `.d-flex` class, then use the `.align-items-center` class to center the text vertically. You could also then add `.justify-content-center` to center it horizontally:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="background-color: #f04e23;">
      <h1 class="display-4 text-center">2018 Speakers</h1>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/400/600" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```